# How to replace form:input with form:checkbox in Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, jsp, model-view-controller

```
<td><label for="admin">Is admin:</label></td>
<td><form:input path="admin" value="${userObject.admin}"/></td>
```

This is works fine: fills input with `true` or `false` according to boolean value in `${userObject.admin}`.

But this does not work as I expected:

```
<td><label for="admin">Is admin:</label></td>
<td><form:checkbox path="admin" id="admin" value="${userObject.admin}"/></td>
```

It always gives unchecked checkbox. Push me, please, in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two tags have not the same semantic for `value` attributes.

`form:input` tag uses `value` attribute to set a default value for a field while 
`form:checkbox` tag uses `value` attribute to **only display** a possible value to check.

When you allow to select multiple checkbox for a field, value is more 
helpful:

```
<form:checkbox path="admin" value="system"/>
<form:checkbox path="admin" value="application"/>
<form:checkbox path="admin" value="local"/>
```

With `form:checkbox` tag, the box is selected or not according to `path` attribute value. Here `admin` field. So, if `admin` field is false, it will not be checked and if it is true, it is checked.
If you want your checkbox be checked, set `admin` field with the expected value.
You can do this processing in `Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)()` method of your controller.